# I am trying to put an transition property on my a tag, when a link is visted to when its hovering to change color

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

This the HTML
    
    
    
        Main Page

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>        
            <nav class="nav-items">

                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_1"><a href="index.html">First</a></li>
                        <li id="li_2"><a href="secondpage.html">Second</a></li>
                        <li id="li_3"><a href="thirdpage.html">Third</a>  </li>
                        <div class="clear">

                </div>
                    </ul>
```

Above is the html for the links which is a floated list with A tags.

```
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the CSS

```
*{
margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}


.container{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: #c7c7c7;

}

.nav-items{
height: 40px;
background-color: #8d8b8b;  
}
 .nav-items ul li{
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
margin: 10px 5px; 
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;


}

.clear{

clear: both;


}


/*a{
  color:   #1f9393;
transition-property: color;
transition-duration: 2s;
}
*/
```

This works^ but I need the code below to work

```
a:link{
color: #f0ffff;
text-decoration: none;

}
a:visited{
text-decoration: none;
color: #1f9393;
transition-property: color;
transition-duration: 2s;

}
a:hover{
color:  #2f2f2f; 
}
a:active{
color: #3e3d3b;
}
```

I need for the visited link to transition to the color when its hovered...what is the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **place the transition in the link, outside the :visited state**.

Right now the transition property is assigned to the link when it has the visited state. When you hover over it the link state changes from visited to hover, and there is no transition assigned to that state. That is why you need to assign the transition to the element directly.

```css
a:link{
color: green;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color 2s;

}
a:visited{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
}
a:hover{
color: black; 
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: Thank!!It works can you please furhter explain why indeed this is needed to be the way it is

Comment: Im so sorry this is difficukt to understand, isnt what I had before transitioning to when there is a change in color which when I hovered the change happened , thus change color?

Comment: The transition property tells the browser "in this element change color during 2seconds". But it needs to be applied in the initial state and in the final state. The way you had it, it was only applied in the initial state (visited)  and not in the final state (hover). It seems like the visited state is **replaced** by the hover state. The way to apply it in both states is either applying the transition also in the hover (so now its twice,visited and hover) or simply in the element itself.

Comment: Everything is clear, but why do you say 'the element' when you are putting it on the a:link, not the actual <a> element. Is a:link considered to be an element?